# function attributes in decorated function

Tags: python, attributes, python-decorators

Is there a way to set all attributes in a decorated function as in the original function?

For example if I take this code:

```
def timeit(f):
    import time
    def new_f(n):
        start = time.time()
        res = f(n)
        end = time.time()
        tt = end-start
        print tt
        return res
    return new_f

@timeit
def fun(n=0):
    ''' docstring '''
    res = 0
    for _ in xrange(n):
        res = res + 1
    return res
```

Then the function *fun* has actually lost all its attributes such as **fun.func_defaults** or **fun.func_dict** or **fun.func_doc**. Is there a generic way to handle this?

Comment: Quoting the accepted answer from the duplicated question: "That's why we have `functools.wraps`. This takes a function used in a decorator and adds the functionality of copying over the function name, docstring, arguments list, etc"

Comment: Thanks - that is exactly what I was looking for. Too bad that it would be really hard to find the relevant question in SO without actually knowing the fuctools.wraps function...